# Did the Soviet Union know when DEFCON levels changed?

Tags: united-states, military, soviet-union, cold-war

The US military uses a scale of alert readiness called [DEFCON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFCON), with DEFCON 5 being the lowest alert level and DEFCON 1 being the highest, preparing for imminent nuclear war.  At least once during the Cold War, readiness was pushed all the way to DEFCON 2.

When DEFCON levels were raised, how secret was this?  Did the Soviet Union know when DEFCON levels changed?

Comment: I imagine if their spies were unable to tell them the exact state that they would notice the increased activity, or be able to make a pretty good guess as it would have been their actions causing those responses.

Comment: @Ryathal: But would going from, say, 5 to 4 result in extra activity discernible to an outside observer?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg after a quick glance at Wikipedia's description of differences a 5 to 4 would probably have been unnoticed (and many places were always at 4), but others definitely would have noticed the difference between other levels especially the USSR

Comment: @FelixGoldberg AFAIK at no point was the US ever at DEFCON 5 prior to the collapse of the USSR, so that's a moot point. The other levels all include marked differences in the deployment of military forces and can thus be detected easily.

Comment: @jwenting: Actually, 5 is the lowest level, so you must have meant 1. But apart from that I guess you're right.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg nope, 5 was never reached either. 5 indicated complete stand down, which never happened, the ICBM silos are manned to this day and the SSBNs are still on patrol for example.

Comment: @jwenting: Not that it's crucial, but wikipedia says that 5 is "Lowest state of readiness" and that "For much of the Cold War, American ICBM sites were at DEFCON 4, rather than 5." From which I surmise that for the rest of the Cold War, it was 5...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg the last few months I think they were officially at 5 after the weapons had been retargeted away from Soviet territory. Also, they were for a good time at 2 or 3, for example during Vietnam, Cuban crisis, etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sometimes it deliberately wasn't kept secret from the enemy. This is from [William Taubman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Taubman)'s *Khrushchev: The Man and His Era*, about the [Cuban missile crisis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuban_missile_crisis#US_alert_level_raised) in 1962:

> At 10:00 A.M., Washington time, when the quarantine went into full
>   effect, the U.S. strategic Command moved from Defense Condition 3 to
>   DEFCON 2, one level below that of general war. For the first time in
>   history all American long-range missiles and bombers were now on alert,
>   and scores of planes loaded with atomic bombs were aloft around the
>   clock, refueled by areal tankers, waiting over Greenland and northern
>   Canada for the signal to proceed toward the assigned Soviet target. To
>   make sure Moscow noticed, the SAC commander, General Thomas Power,
>   took it upon himself to "announce" the move in uncoded message to his
>   men.

A footnote identifies the following source for the last sentence:

> Laurence Chang and Peter Kornbluh, eds., 
>   *The Cuban Missile Crisis, 1962: A National Security Archive Documents Reader*
>   (New York, New Press, 1992), p. 371.

An "announcement" would also seem to make sense under the logic of nuclear deterrence. I can't confirm whether Power's communication contained the verbatim phrase DEFCON 2, but perhaps it did, because at this point (one hopes) nobody wanted to issue ambiguous commands.